# Retrieve last_visited value in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

According to the Aerospike [docs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/scan.html#read-write-scan) you can

> use a UDF to compare the last_visited value of a record

**How do you access the last_visited value of a record?** It is not included in the records metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its implying the last time the record was "touched". It has to be an update, not merely a read. A read does not change the record in any way. A touch operation on the record updates its metadata. In the metadata, look for last_update_time (LUT) (introduced ver 3.8.3+).  You can access a record's last_update_time only inside a UDF (Lua - User Defined Function) as [record.last_update_time](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api/record.html).